# Triggered emails directly from Marketing cloud

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud

Can I send triggered emails directly from Salesforce Marketing cloud to subscribers. Our Marketing cloud is not connected to any external CRM like Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from a [**Welcome Email**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/solution_guides/welcome_email/), firing off a [**Triggered Email**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/) requires an API call.

If your audience is in a Data Extension, List, Group, etc., you can send [**User-Initiated Emails**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/email_messages/how_to_send_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/) on an interval with an [**Automation**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/) or Program.